# Windows PowerShell and Batch: why are `=` and `.` used to split a command line argument to multiple ones?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

When running testing executables compiled from [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest), I found this annoying issue: a command line argument like "`-tc=some.test.case`" is not passed to the executable as-is.

So the following experiment proves there is some special treating of an argument like "`-a=b.c`", with equal sign and period among it.

Give this simple batch script:

```
@echo off
echo 0: %0
echo 1: %1
echo 2: %2
echo 3: %3
```

I invoke it in PowerShell and "Command Prompt".

In PowerShell, one argument can be split into three:

```
PS D:\work
> .\args.bat -a=b.c
0: "D:\work\args.bat"
1: -a
2: b
3: .c
PS D:\work
>
PS D:\work
> .\args.bat '-a=b.c'
0: "D:\work\args.bat"
1: -a
2: b.c
3:
PS D:\work
>
PS D:\work
> .\args.bat "-a=b.c"
0: "D:\work\args.bat"
1: -a
2: b.c
3:
PS D:\work
>
PS D:\work
> .\args.bat `"-a=b.c`"
0: "D:\work\args.bat"
1: "-a=b.c"
2:
3:
```

In "Command Prompt", it can be split in two:

```
D:\work>type args.bat
@echo off
echo 0: %0
echo 1: %1
echo 2: %2
echo 3: %3

D:\work>args.bat -a=b.c
0: args.bat
1: -a
2: b.c
3:

D:\work>args.bat "-a=b.c"
0: args.bat
1: "-a=b.c"
2:
3:

D:\work>args.bat '-a=b.c'
0: args.bat
1: '-a
2: b.c'
3:
```

Why is it so? Is it any rationale behind it, or is it just some bug?

[image: screenshot]

Update 1:

I've created a simple C program to compile a simplistic executable:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("arg[%d]: {%s}\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program is compiled using Visual Studio 2015's  "VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt", build command is just: `cl args.c`.

The result seems different for the "`=`" char handling, when passed to EXE, the `=` character is not used as separator. Just can't get the logic behind all this...

[image: exe result]

Command Prompt result with executable:

```
C:\temp>args.exe -a=b.c
arg[0]: {args.exe}
arg[1]: {-a=b.c}
```

PowerShell result with executable:

```
> .\args.exe -a=b.c
arg[0]: {C:\temp\args.exe}
arg[1]: {-a=b}
arg[2]: {.c}
```

Comment: For the Windows Command Prompt and therefore for batch files, the following characters act as token separators: _space_, _tab_, `,`, `;`, `=`, _vtab_ (`0x0B`), _ff_ (`0x0C`) and _nbsp_ (`0xFF`), all of which lose their special meaning when placed in between a pair of quotation marks (`"`); the apostrophe (`'`) does not have any particular meaning at all. For PowerShell I do not know. As for why: well, I guess, you will have to ask the responsible employees at Microsoft…

Comment: You would have to double quote it in cmd to be taken as one argument.

Comment: @aschipfl  I've created an executable to test (update appended to question section), it seems that for an exe, `=` is not used as separator.  Meanwhile, that dot `.` is always interpreted as argument separator in PowerShell. I can accept there are quirks in "Command Prompt", but PowerShell as it is a carefully designed modern "shell", why is it behaving so strangely with the "dot" character...

Comment: The `=` is handled differently by your `.exe` because it is your `.exe` that does the argument parsing but not `cmd.exe`. Though when you use a batch file, `cmd.exe` does the argument parsing…